# Kafka with .net core docker file config

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, apache-kafka

My app is .net core 3.1 based. Trying to connect to kafka , publish and consume topics. Locally the code is working fine no error .Running the code in wsl2 ubuntu env using vs code. Now I want to create a docker image for the same code and publish in azure. The docker image is getting created but while trying to run the image getting error

> No provider for SASL mechanism GSSAPI:Recompile librdkafka with libsasal2 or openssl support. Current build options:Plain Sasl_scram ouathbearer.

Please help with the docker file as what exactly to install and how to do so

Docker file :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sasl2-bin \
        libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit\
        krb5-user \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev\
        libzstd-dev
RUN echo "Done"


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["abc.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./abc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./abc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "abc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "abc.dll"]
```

Comment: As the error indicates, you'll need a Docker layer that compiles the librdkafka source code (refer its github page on those steps), after the apt steps that install some compilation libraries

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok I will try it..thnks